# RestTemplate: exchange() vs postForEntity() vs execute()

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am working on Rest API using Spring boot and I had to access an application's endpoint. I used `RestTemplate` for it. I was able to do it using 2 methods,

- **`postForEntity()`**:

  ```
  responseEntity = 
      restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, httpEntity, ResponseClass.class);
  ```
- **`exchange()`**:

  ```
  responseEntity = 
      restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, ResponseClass.class);
  ```

I would like to know the usage and differences of these two methods.

I also see another method `execute()`. Please shed some light on it. How and when to use it.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The `RestTemplate` is a very versatile object.

Let's start with **`execute`**, since it's the most generic method:

```
execute(String url, HttpMethod method, @Nullable RequestCallback requestCallback,
        @Nullable ResponseExtractor<T> responseExtractor, Object... uriVariables)
```

Note the `uriVariables` can be passed as a `Map` too.

`execute` is designed to be applicable in the highest variety of scenarios possible:

- The first and second parameters allow any valid combination of URL and method.
- The request can be modified in a myriad of different ways by passing a custom `RequestCallback` (a `@FunctionalInterface` with just one method `doWithRequest(ClientHttpRequest request)`) before sending it.
- The response returned from the remote resource can be deserialized in any way necessary by passing a custom `ResponseExtractor`.

Compare this with **`exchange`**:

```
exchange(String url, HttpMethod method, @Nullable HttpEntity<?> requestEntity,
         Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables)
```

There are two major differences here:

- You can now pass an `HttpEntity` directly, whereas before it needed to be set manually using the `RequestCallback`.
- Deserialization mechanics are provided out of the box by passing the desired response type `Class`.

As you can see, this is much more convenient for everyday use.

Methods like **`getForEntity`** and **`postForEntity`** are even shorter, easier to understand versions of this:

```
getForEntity(String url, Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables)

postForEntity(String url, @Nullable Object request, Class<T> responseType,
              Object... uriVariables)
```

Notice `postForEntity` now allows you to POST any `Object` directly without a wrapper. There is no performance benefit or detriment to using these instead of `execute`, as they call `execute` themselves under the hood - it's simply a matter of convenience.

Answer (score 10):

[`RestTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) is a *synchronous* client to perform HTTP requests. It offers templates for common scenarios for each HTTP method, in addition to the generalized `exchange(...)` and `execute(...)` methods that support less frequent cases.

The [Spring Integration documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#rest-client-access) summarizes the usage of each method:

> ### `postForEntity`
>
> Create a new resource via `POST` and return the representation from the response.

> ### `exchange`
>
> More generalized, and less opinionated version, of the above methods that provides extra flexibility when needed. It accepts `RequestEntity`, including HTTP method, URL,  headers, and body as input, and returns a `ResponseEntity`.
>
> These methods allow the use of `ParameterizedTypeReference` instead of `Class` to specify a response type with generics.

> ### `execute`
>
> The most generalized way to perform a request, with full control over request preparation and response extraction via callback interfaces.

---

In the end, both `postForEntity(...)`, `exchange(...)` and `execute(...)` methods will invoke the protected [`doExecute(...)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#doExecute-java.net.URI-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.web.client.RequestCallback-org.springframework.web.client.ResponseExtractor-) method, which will perform the actual HTTP request. You can check the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.java) for details

Answer (score 4):

**Execute(..)** 
The most raw form of method, to make REST call.

**Exchange(..)**
A wrapper over Execute method.

**PostForEntity(..)**
A wrapper method, which further eases the use for making REST calls.
You specify the request type in the method name itself(getForEntity, postForEntity), so,
need not mention request type in the parameter.
The method name in itself becomes self explanatory.

In **Exchange & postForEntity**, response has to be in **Json formats**. 
This Json is further converted to Model class by json-mapper libraries.
While, in **Execute**, we accept response in **any format**, as we pass the deserializer in Response Executor argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the implementation of both postForEntity and exchange method you will see that both use the execute methods in the back. Using the exchange method will give you more freedom for calling different http methods.